# Подключение библиотеки в Eclipse

Tags: c, cmake, include, makefile

Скомпилировал и установил архивы библиотеки в директорию `/usr/local/lib/`. Вывод после `sudo make install`:

```
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libcollectc.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libcollectc.a
```

Но не могу понять как правильно теперь к архиву добраться с Eclipse. Пробовал указывать `Lib path` в `properties` но результата нет.

Comment: `-L/usr/local/lib` и `-lcollect`, там же вроде gcc или clang? вот в опциях и добавьте.

Comment: ну может код приведете чтобы хотя бы посмотреть какие проперти вы там добавили?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, пробовал '-lcollect' но безрезультатно. Архивы лежат на месте, все проверил.

Comment: @UjinUkr  `-lcollectc`, во-первых, во-вторых, «без результатно» не бывает — всегда есть какие-то ошибки... в-третьих, с эклипсом не работал, но свойство должно называться `link flags`, `link libraries` или ещё как-то так, а `Lib path` скорей всего предназначен для `-L`-флагов...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, сделал по другому, указал путь в директорию через проводник, но include все ровно файлы не видит.

Comment: @UjinUkr, ну дык include'то установил? или прописал до них путь?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, в настройках линковки забил адрес, а в include  имя файла нужного

Comment: @UjinUkr, путь до хедера нужно забивать не в настройки линковки, а в путь для поиска хедера (ключ `-I` компилятора)... и как обычно «не верю»... точные пути, имена настроек и результаты в студию...